# how to store fingerprint data along with username, image, email etc in database in android app

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

how to store fingerprint data along with username, image, email etc in database in android app. I read out many links but it is not helpful. they are

1. [How to get Fingerprint input from user and save to sqlite in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160643/how-to-get-fingerprint-input-from-user-and-save-to-sqlite-in-android)
2. [Retrieving Fingerprint data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157708/retrieving-fingerprint-data)  [Get fingerprint templates from fingerprint scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841963/get-fingerprint-templates-from-fingerprint-scanner)
3. [Register user fingerprint in an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278532/register-user-fingerprint-in-an-android-application)

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get key from keystore on successful fingerprint auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724749/how-to-get-key-from-keystore-on-successful-fingerprint-auth)

Comment: Every answer in the links given reiterate the same thing; you cannot store the fingerprint data.

Answer (score 6):

As per [Nexus](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6300638?hl=en) FAQs

> Your fingerprint data is stored securely and never leaves your Pixel
>   or Nexus phone. Your fingerprint data isn't shared with Google or any
>   apps on your device. Apps are notified only whether your fingerprint
>   was verified.

FingeprintManager only has these 3 features:

`authenticate()` : for authenticating user

`hasEnrolledFingerprints()` : Determine if there is at least one fingerprint enrolled.

`isHardwareDetected()` : Determine if fingerprint hardware is present and functional.

There is no method to get fingerprint id from the sensor. So your idea of storing fingerprints in database won't work.

Comment: How about using any third party sdk to read and save fingerprint to the db? Are there any such sdk's?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save a fingerprint image or template. It is stated by Android in the [Fingerprint Section](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html).

The Fingerprint data is stored by android system in the phone at a secure location which is not accessible. You can write an app that gets and stores fingerprint to authenticate the user. You can go through this sample that demonstrates to use registered fingerprints to authenticate the user in your app.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog

Comment: Hi Abhi, Thanking you for response !!

Comment: when you say store, as in storing the fingerprint data that can be matched in future in a database? Lol i'm getting excited about this as i'm planning to build something with it.

Comment: Yes the fingerprint is stored by Android. However, you can't access this location. In technical terms, the fingerprints in Android are stored in an isolated environment that cannot be accessed by any external means. So, matching the fingerprint data doesn't seem possible :(

Comment: @Abhi what if we do not want to get stored fingerprint. I want to scan and store my own fingerprint somewhere else in separate android application using device fingerprint scanner.

Comment: @Abhi can we use device fingerprint scanner for our own use ?