# login/authentication with fingerprint

Tags: java, android, authentication, fingerprint

We're implementing an android application that needs to collaborate with the fingerprint sensor. After any installation of the application, a login page will prompt and the user must add a username along with fingerprint.

I read something about that the applications can't collaborate with the fingerprint sensor. However, I thought maybe someone has an idea.

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE:**
The thing that prevents me from achieving that is the `BiometricPrompt` which gives a true/false state. I need the exact value of a fingerprint and send the data to the server for a specific username.

Comment: what exactly is your question ?

Comment: You can try `BiometricPrompt` for fingerprint  [check here](https://medium.com/mindorks/fingerprint-authentication-using-biometricprompt-compat-1466365b4795)

Comment: @a_local_nobody Authorize a user on an android application with a fingerprint instead of a password. In addition, the fingerprint data isn't stored on a particular phone, it stored on a server.

Comment: what is preventing _you_ from achieving that ? what have you tried ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody `BiometricPrompt` gives a true/false state. I need the exact value of a fingerprint and send the data to the server for a specific username.

Comment: you should update your question to make that more clear, if you're specifically trying to get the fingerprint that should be added to your question

Comment: @a_local_nobody Just updated. So, can I accomplish that?

Comment: i'm not sure :) but your updated question will find answers hopefully

Comment: no problem, you should always try to include what you've done and what's preventing you from achieving your goal in your questions, otherwise it sounds like you simply want code as a solution and haven't tried anything. i hope you find an answer now :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you want to store user information with their credentials and their fingerprint then **it's not possible.**

Fingerprint data will never be shared with anyone. Google has strict guidelines

Check this for more info : [Understand fingerprint security](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6300638?hl=en)

This might also help you : [How to store fingerprint data along with username, image, email etc in database in android app ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813525/how-to-store-fingerprint-data-along-with-username-image-email-etc-in-database)