# How to build an apps to register fingerprint for authentication usage

Tags: android, authentication, fingerprint

Hi I have the same case like this question [how to store fingerprint data along with username, image, email etc in database in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813525/how-to-store-fingerprint-data-along-with-username-image-email-etc-in-database) and I have read that and some of the answers there. It is stated that we can not get something like template of fingerprint that user registered in android because it is stored at a secure location. I just want to make sure that, is that true if I say something like this: Because of android doesn't give a permission to access template of user fingerprint so we can not build a mobile apps to register our fingerprint in that apps by using android scanner of fingerprint, is that right if I say something like that?

So my point here is the way to register our fingerprint in a mobile apps, I haven't found yet articles to show step by step build mobile apps like what I mean before